# PHP convert Image file to binary string

Tags: php, sql, binary, sqlplus, binary-data

I want to convert an image I retrieve from a form to binary string so that I can insert it into a sqlplus table. I've looked around at how to do this conversion and I found that most solutions have this:

**example table:**

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    image_id int,
    image blob 
    PRIMARY KEY (image_id));
```

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./Upload/UploadImage.php">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span><br/>
<input type="submit" name="uploadImage" value="Upload Image"></form>
```

**Proposed Conversion Solution:**

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    $encoded_data = base64_encode($data);
    //echo the data to check it's there
    echo "Encoded Data: " . $encoded_data;
?>
```

If I echo `$data` I get a jumbled string, but if i echo `$encoded_data` I just get: `Encoded Data:` then nothing.

I want to be able to insert this binary data into my db using

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO images VALUES (1, \'' . $encoded_data . '\')';
```

*(I know this is just the sql string - the execution of the statement is not something I felt I needed to include).*

**UPDATE:** I realized I had a type in my `$encoded_data = base64_encode($data);` line so that works now but the sql throws a string literal too long error.

Comment: I highly suggest storing images in the DB.

Comment: it is unfortunately a requirement that I store this as a blob. Although I recognize this is not realistically practical.

Comment: What if you `var_dump($data)`?  Storing files in DB causes high traffic between DB and Web server

Comment: Just store `$data` that's what BLOB is for.  You still need to escape it with `mysqli_real_escape_string` or use prepared statements.

Comment: I realized that my ``$encoded_data = base64_encode($data);`` had a typo. So now that works. @AbraCadaver I am using sqlplus not mysql - I tried using addslashes($data) but it causes an unknown error in my sql execution. If I use the encoded data i get the string literal too long error.

Comment: What's the field type for image in your table? Is it text or something else?

Comment: Then you don't need to use `base64_encode` you can directly save the result of `file_get_contents`. If you worry about some illegal words you can apply `mysql_escape_string` to content

Comment: @Javad That's the first thing I tried ``$sql = 'INSERT INTO images VALUES (1, \'' . $encoded_data . '\')';`` followed by ``$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);`` and ``$res = oci_execute($stid);`` but it seems to have an error and it must be undefined because I try to print the error, but it doesn't doesn't output one.

Comment: I guess it's not because of PHP it's because of your DB which is SQLPlus (I found this article about SQLPlus and PHP [http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm] please check the *Using LOBs: Uploading and Querying Images* seciotn)

Comment: @Javad ah you are correct - the solution provided in that article is suitable. Thank you for pointing me towards this article it has proven most useful for a few other things I was working on as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$db_img = fread($fp, filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$db_img = addslashes($db_img);
$db_img = base64_decode($db_img);
```

then

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO images VALUES (1,'$db_img')"
```